# Converting "string" date to "date" format using FME

Tags: file-geodatabase, fme-form, date

I have a string field with values such as 04.07.21 and I am trying to write to GDB but it's not working because date format is expected and string is provided.

How can I convert these values (04.07.21) to date format in FME?

Comment: Which version are you using - there has been changes in DateTime transformer(s) over the the past versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @nielsgerrits says, the DateTimeConverter transformer is the way to go. Its parameters would look something like this:

[image]

The input format is set to:

```
%d.%m.%y2099
```

Why that? Well, firstly I'm assuming that it is 4th July and not 7th April (so *%d.%m*, not *%m.%d*) but secondly, the year is only a two-digit year. The lower-case %y format works for 1900-1999 only, so we have to give "a greatest year" to consider (see the Quick Reference info in the transformer dialog).

That will return the value:

```
20210704
```

That date is in an FME structure. Do we now have to convert it to a Geodatabase datetime structure? No. The Geodatabase writer will do that automatically when it writes the data.

Coincidentally, there is a webinar on datetimes in FME later this week. See **[this page](https://www.safe.com/webinars/save-the-date-for-quality-data-making-use-of-datetime/)** for more details. It may help you to learn some of the capabilities of these transformers and functions.

Comment: thanks a lot, I never understood "%y####" but now I do

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use the DateFormatter/[DateTimeConverter](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/datetimeconverter.htm) transformer. You need to convert to yyyymmdd or yyyymmddhhmmss to write to the date / datetime field in a File Geodatabase.

Comment: can you explain how transformer parameters should look like ?

Comment: I am looking solution at Date/Time Functions --> @DateTimeParse()...

Comment: Just see the documentation, nothing difficult?
From %d.%m.%y to %y%m%d.

Answer (score 1):

Year 2023, you can do this:

Format date into one with FME (part 1) Regex filter

https://transparentgov.net/cleargov1/1193/format-date-into-one-with-fme-part-1-regex-filter

Format date into one with FME (part 2) FME attribute creator

https://transparentgov.net/cleargov1/1194/format-date-into-one-with-fme-part-2-fme-attribute-creator

Format date into one with FME (part 3) FME Date Time converter

https://transparentgov.net/cleargov1/1195/format-date-into-one-with-fme-part-3-fme-date-time-converter